# Multiplayer game await/async Firebase error

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication, multiplayer

I'm encountering an async/await issue while using Firebase to authenticate a user with SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync() in a multiplayer game built using Netcode, Relay, Lobby, and Authentication.
Here is the code, which is triggered by the press of a login button:

```
if(auth == null) {Debug.Log("auth is null");}
 
 FirebaseUser AttemptedUser = null;

 //Call the Firebase auth signin function passing the email and password
 try
 {
  Debug.Log("about to try to log in with email and password"); //<----- LINE 1
  AttemptedUser = await auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(_email, _password);
  Debug.Log("finished awaiting SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync"); <----- LINE 2
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
  Debug.Log(e.GetType());
  Debug.Log(e.Message);
 }
 finally
 {
  Debug.Log("in FAM finally");
  //User is now logged in, so get the result
  User = AttemptedUser;
  Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})", User.DisplayName, User.Email);
  //change the UI
  warningLoginText.text = "";
  confirmLoginText.text = "Logged In";
 
  Debug.Log("about to call UnityLogin");
  //log them into Unity
  await UnityLogin(anonymous: false);
  Debug.Log("finished calling UnityLogin");
 }
```

Problem:
Everything after the await call (Debug.Log("finished awaiting SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync"); and onwards into the finally block) does not get called until after I exit the game (by hitting the play button in the editor to stop the game). Specifically, the line which is commented "LINE 1" runs, but "LINE 2" does not run until exiting the game.

Interestingly, when playing the game after first loading the game, this code runs fine no problem. However, after loading a new scene, joining a Relay allocation and Lobby, and then leaving the Lobby and reloading this menu scene, the await line hangs and suspends the following code in that snippet until I exit the game, so, something to do with loading the other scenes or hosting/joining a relay/lobby must  be messing with the await line. Any help is extremely appreciated as I am in a rush to publish this game.

Thanks!

- Seforius.

Comment: It sounds like your synchronization context is getting erased

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can I use synchronization contexts to deal with this error? I heard about synchronization contexts but couldn't find many specifics.

Comment: If you change the login so its not async does it work? If it does, do you really need login to be async?

Comment: I don't think the login can be changed to not async. It uses the SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync from Firebase which is inherently Async. Changing it to not be Async would not allow for any error handling on the Firebase login function; I think it has to be awaited.

Comment: Also, @Blindy, I just Debug.Logged the synchronization context right before the call and right after the call (after the call is only visible once I end the game) and they both show up as UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext

Comment: Is your code blocking anywhere further up your call stack, or is it using async all the way?

Comment: Hi @StephenCleary, this is the flow/call stack: user presses button -> normal function called -> async function called -> SignInWithEmailAndPasswordsync is called and blocks the code under it.

Comment: So, the "normal" function is calling the `async` function and then blocking on the returned task?

Comment: "they both show up as UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext" -- that's the type, yes, but are they the same instance?

Comment: @StephenCleary apologies - let me restate the stack. I just reviewed the code and it goes like this: user presses button -> async OnClick is called -> async Login is called -> async SignInWithEmailAndPassword is called. All async calls are explicitly preceded by an await statement (except for the OnClick, since it’s triggered by a button). The SignInWithEmailAndPassword function comes from the FirebaseAuth Unity package. Only the code directly after the SignIn call seems to be blocked until exiting the game, at which point it runs.

Comment: @Blindy how could I check whether or not the instances are the same? Currently I am checking the System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current variable. How could I get the “instance”? Could I perhaps get the hash code of the .Current object? Any ideas would be appreciated